# Class diagram: How to show a user can assign role to another user?

Tags: mysql, sql, uml, class-diagram

Lets say I have User and Role classes in my UML class diagram. User has one to many relationship with Role class

Attributes of User class: username, password, email

Attributes of Role class: roleType

[image]
According to problem specification, a user can invite another user and assign roles. How can I show this relationship in class diagram?

Comment: Just a point, your class Role has one attribute only with getter and setter ( I guess). Could it be more effiecient to just add an attribute of type UserRole in class User ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, either you make the `Role` a public attribute of `User`

[image]

or you add an operation

[image]

(and probably a couple more of that) to assign (and eventually remove) `Role`s. Here I made `role` a protected attribute. Feel free to make it private and add query operations at your wish.